# What is the purpose of converting a level-set function into a signed distance function?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

In the paper [*Electrical impedance tomography using level set representation and total variational regularization*](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2004.11.022), the authors tried to implement an iterative algorithm to find the interface of two regions containing different materials. They mentioned the use of level set function to represent an interface of the two regions. Then, they stated first the *signed distance function*, defined in the following:

> Consider a bounded Lipschitz domain $ \Omega = \Omega_1 \cup \Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n $, where $\Omega_1$ is contained 'inside its own boundary'. Let $ \Gamma = \partial \Omega_1 $. The signed distance function $ \phi(x) $ in between a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a set $ \Gamma \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as:
> $$ \phi(x) = \begin{cases} d(x,\Gamma), & \text{if } x \in \Omega_1, \\ -d(x,\Gamma), & \text{if } x \in \Omega_2. \end{cases} $$

The author then mention that this function satisfies the partial differential equation
$$ \lvert \nabla \phi \rvert = 1 \quad \text{for all } x \in \Omega. $$
But the author goes on and mentions another partial differential equation where the signed distance function is the unique steady state solution to that equation. The equation is
\begin{equation}
\tag{*}\label{eq:*}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} + \operatorname{sign}(\phi) (\lvert \nabla \phi \rvert - 1) = 0, \quad \phi(x, 0) = \tilde{\phi}
\end{equation}
where $ \tilde\phi $ is any arbitrary level set function that is positive in $ \Omega_1 $, negative in $ \Omega_2 $ and zero on $ \Gamma$.

The author stated that during the iteration procedure, one may regularise the level set function using \eqref{eq:*} to obtain a corresponding signed distance function.

My main question is

> Are there any specific reasons that one might need to perform such regularization?

My initial thought is that since the main objective of the algorithm is to resolve the boundary, there is no need to do so and it is only for easier computations. However, I am not too sure about this.